# Finding a closed form for this expression

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Evaulate: $$\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{4^k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-x}}{e^{kx}}(1+e^x)^{2k}dx$$
Where $n$ is a natural number.

I tried using the binomial theorem on $(1+e^x)^{2k}$ which gave:

$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{4^k}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^ne^{-x}}{e^{kx}}\sum_{r=0}^{2k} \binom {2k}{r} e^{rx}dx$$
After which I interchanged the integration and summation (I'm not sure if this is allowed in this case)

$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{4^k}\sum_{r=0}^{2k} \binom {2k}{r}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^n e^{-(k+1-r)x}dx$$
Substituing $v = (k+1-r)x$,

$$=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{4^k}\sum_{r=0}^{2k} \binom {2k}{r}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{v^n}{(k+1-r)^{n+1}}e^{-v}dv$$

Now as $n$ is a natural number, using the gamma function, this becomes:

$$=\frac{n!}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac {1}{4^k}\sum_{r=0}^{2k} \binom {2k}{r}\frac{1}{(k+1-r)^{n+1}}$$

I have absolutely no idea on how to continue further and I'm not even sure about the steps I've done so far.
Any help with the original expression or with this new expression would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\sum_k\frac{(1+e^x)^{2k}}{4^ke^{kx}}$ is a geometric series...

Comment: ... which does not converge if $x > 0$.  Also, the integrals don't converge.

Comment: So this doesn't converge? :(

Comment: @Nikunj Should it?

Comment: @user Yes. In fact, the closed form should be related to the Riemann Zeta function.

Comment: Could you give a reference? It is hard to imagine that a divergent sum (integral) can have a meaning.

Comment: The innermost integrand function behaves like $x^n e^{(k-1)x}$ for large values of $k$ and $x$, and this is not an integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. I guess the term $(1+e^x)^{2k}$ should have been $$(1+e^x)^{\color{red}-2k}.$$

Comment: Yes. I see now, I've made a mistake in between and landed on this integral. Thank you all for your inputs.

Comment: @Nikunj can you edit the question with the correct exponent and provide some progress?

Comment: @Integrand Please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3737988/different-ways-of-evaluating-int-0-infty-fracxn-dxex-12